# Upgrade sqlite3 version using python 2.7.3 and pysqlite2 2.6.3

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

Good day.

I have been learning python and sqlite recently and have trouble installing the latest version of sqlite3 (3.7.14.1). I am using python 2.7.3 in windows 7 and have installed the latest pysqlite2 version (2.6.3) using the windows installer. I have used the following code to import pysqlite and check the versions and these are the results:

```
>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.3'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.6.2'
```

Based on the code above, the sqlite3 version used is an older one. I have downloaded the latest sqlite3.dll and have overwritten the one found in Python27\DLLs\ directory. But when I run sqlite3.sqlite_version, it still gives me the old version. However, when using the default python sqlite3 module it shows an old version of the module (2.6.0) and the latest version of the sqlite3.dll I just copied. See code below:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.14.1'
```

My question is, how do I upgrade pysqlite2 2.6.3's sqlite3 3.7.14.1? Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pysqlite2` installer you probably got from [here](http://code.google.com/p/pysqlite/downloads/list) contains `sqlite3` compiled into `_sqlite.pyd`, it doesn't use the dll found in the DLLs directory (that one is only uset by the `sqlite3` module).

So if you want to upgrade the sqlite version used, you'll have to recompile `pysqlite2` yourself.

Or, as `pysqlite2` is virtually identical to `sqlite3`, you could also replace the complete package with a file `pysqlite2.py` conaining only:

```
from sqlite3 import *
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, the sqlite3.dll has been compiled from source to _sqlite.pyd. As for compiling pysqlite2, I have tried it but I get an error. It may have something to do with not having a c compiler to compile the sqlite3 source. I will try to install a c compiler and try again if I get the same error.

Comment: As for the second option, do you mean delete the entire contents of the pysqlite2 directory and place a pysqlite2.py?

Comment: yes, exactly. that way you would use sqlite3 instead of pysqlite2, while keeping backward compatibility with modules importing the latter.

Comment: But wouldn't that still use the old version of sqlite3 module?

Comment: yes, it would use whatever `sqlite3` module is installed. It's the same as `pysqlite2`, only with a different name and a dynamically linked `_sqlite.pyd`, so it uses `sqlite3.dll` which you can change. `pysqlite2` is statically linked, so it uses the sqlite3 version it was linked against. If you really need to update both to the newest version you need to compile it yourself.

Comment: I have chosen to do the compile option but have been having trouble. Here is the link to my problem, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263275/having-trouble-compiling-pysqlite-on-windows). I hope you can help me with it. If I can't get it to compile, I have no other choice but to use the default sqlite3 package but with the updated sqlite3.dll. Thank you.