# Having trouble compiling pysqlite on windows

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

Good day.

I am having trouble compiling pysqlite on windows. I have managed to start compiling with quite a bit of work but now I am stuck with this error:

> d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3

I have searched for possible solutions but most of the solutions are for linux.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when compiling `pysqlite2` from source, you need to edit the file `setup.cfg` which by default should look like:

```
[build_ext]
#define=
#include_dirs=/usr/local/include
#library_dirs=/usr/local/lib
libraries=sqlite3
define=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
```

You'll need to uncomment `include_dirs` and `library_dirs` (remove the `#`) an make sure `include_dirs` points to the directory with the sqlite3 headers, and `library_dirs` to where `sqlite3.dll` can be found.

Now you should be able to compile and install pysqlite2. After that, you should put `sqlite3.dll` somwhere it can be found (either somewhere on the `PATH`, or into `Python27\Lib\site-packages\pysqlite2`)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `import sqlite3` instead and follow this [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) tutorial. That worked fine for me when dealing with Sqlite3 in Python. If that package doesn't exist try upgrading your version of Python instead, because that will include other useful packages.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am already using the latest version of Python which is 2.7.3. The sqlite3 package that comes with python is an older version, 2.6.0. The latest version of pysqlite is 2.6.3. I am trying to compile the latest version.