# How to automatically append slug to URL?

Tags: django, url, slug

I am currently learning Django and would like to know how to automatically append the slug to the url.

For example, the full url to an old question I posted here is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263275/having-trouble-compiling-pysqlite-on-windows
```

But if I enter:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263275
```

in the address bar, it automatically appends the slug in the url.

How do I do this in Django?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have URL patterns for `/questions/13263275/having-trouble-compiling-pysqlite-on-windows` and `/questions/13263275` yet? Have you written a view for either one? Do you have a model with a slug field?

Comment: I just started learning. I recently finished the Django tutorial and Marina Mele's tutorial. And no, I don't have a model with a slug field yet. Adding the slug field probably won't be a problem (right?). It's the appending part in the address bar that's gets me scratching my head. I tried searching in google but just returned empty handed.

Comment: Hopefully it won't be too tricky to add a slug field, but it probably is a required step. You can redirect by using [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) with `HttpResponseRedirect`. You can then simplify the code further by using the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut. I asked all those questions to encourage you to include as much code as you can in your answer, so that we can see exactly where you're stuck, and hopefully so that you learn a bit more while implementing this feature.

Comment: Hi. I have added the slug field to one of my models and added the necessary urls in my urls.py. But I think I see how to do it based on what you posted and the example in the answer below. Once the url matches the pattern with id, e.g. '<int:pk>/', I then use redirect to send the user to a url with the attached slug, e.g. '<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/'. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by taking 2 parameters in URL one `pk` of the question and other `slug` and handle like this.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.questionDetail),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w.-]+)/$', views.questionDetail, name='question-detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
def questionDetail(request, pk, *args):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk) 
    slug = ""
    if(*args[0])
        slug = *args[0]

    if question.slug != slug:
        return redirect('question-detail', pk, question.slug)

    return render(request, 'questions/question_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: This will redirect `/1/wrong-slug/` to `/1/correct-slug/`, but you also want to be able to redirect `/1/` to `/1/correct-slug/`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. I'll give this a shot when I get back to work and will report back. I'll also try to experiment a bit with this code.

Comment: Hi. Manage to get this working with a few tweaks of my own. Thanks for the help guys.